# Create a user on database A with a procedure from database B (with EXECUTE AS)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, security, sql-server-2017

I have 2 logins :

- LoginA: role dbcreator + CONNECT ANY DATABASE
- LoginB: role sysadmin

I have 2 databases :

- dbA: everyone has all rights on it
- dbB: only LoginB has rights on it, LoginA is only the owner of that database but no more

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a user (linked to LoginA) in dbB from a stored procedure of dbA.
Considering this stored procedure has to be executed by LoginA.
Maybe some kind of "EXECUTE AS" mechanism could help ?
Also I have issues about how to use a "USE [dbB]" in a stored procedure.

The solution can have some rights modification,
but these can't give securityadmin nor sysadmin roles.

Here is what is done for now but clearly there is a lot of debug and functionalities to go, but the spirit of what I wanna do is in here :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbB_UserAfterRestore] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    USE [dbB]
    CREATE USER [HOSTNAME\LoginA] FOR LOGIN [HOSTNAME\LoginA]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [HOSTNAME\LoginA]
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [HOSTNAME\LoginA]
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LoginA` is not member of `sysadmin` server role, the login must need `IMPERSONATE` permissions to use `EXECUTE AS` i.e.

```
USE dbB;
CREATE USER LoginA for login LoginA; -- This will create user under "public" database role
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::LoginB to LoginA; -- This is required to use "EXECUTE AS"
```

Once `LoginA` got IMPERSONATE access, you can create procedure as follows in `dbA` where `LoginA` got full access (db_owner)

```
use dbA
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [UserAfterRestore] 
    @TargetDBName varchar(128),
    @GranteeLogin varchar(128),
    @ExecuteAs varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @TSQL varchar(2000);

    SELECT @TSQL = 'USE [' + @DBName + ']; 
                    Execute as user = '''+ @ExecuteAs +'''; 
                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM SYS.database_principals WHERE name = '''+ @GranteeLogin +''')
                        BEGIN
                            CREATE USER [' + @GranteeLogin + '] FOR LOGIN ['+ @GranteeLogin + '];
                        END
                        ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER ['+ @GranteeLogin +'];
                        ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER ['+ @GranteeLogin +'];'
    Print 'Executing: ' + @TSQL

    EXEC (@TSQL);
END
GO
```

Call procedure as follows:

```
exec dbA.dbo.[UserAfterRestore] 
        @TargetDBName = dbB, 
        @GranteeLogin = 'LoginA', 
        @ExecuteAs = 'LoginB';
```

---

If the target is multiple databases, then `LoginA` must be either member of `sysadmin` server role or must be user of all databases (under public role) and GRANTED for IMPERSONATE on respective database's `db_owner`

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, but I modified it a bit on my current context. Used a `EXECUTE as login` instead of `user` on database [master] and `GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::LoginB to LoginA`. By the way instead of creating the user or giving sysadmin role, I only gave `CONNECT ANY DATABASE` right to LoginA.

Comment: @Hybris95, That's great, as long as `LoginB` is `sysadmin` or `db_owner` of all databases

Comment: `LoginB` is `sa` ;)